# adaptiveThreshold getting blank (full white) image

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.0, threshold, adaptive-threshold

I want to apply adaptiveThreshold using open cv library to my bitmap image, but once i do with following code, it shows blank (full white) image, please help me to resolve it.

following is code:

```
Mat grayMat = imread(getImageUri(this, photo).getPath(), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat resultMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(grayMat, resultMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 40);
        Bitmap imgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resultMat.cols(), resultMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: How did you assign the `resultMat` to the `imgBitmap`? To me it looks like you just instantiate the size and type of the bitmap.

Comment: Thank you Rick M, I just created imgBitmap like this only, how can i pass above bitmap to ImageView, pls help

Comment: @RickM Utils.matToBitmap(resultMat, imgBitmap); i used this, but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line after init. bitmap

```
Utils.matToBitmap(resultMat, imgBitmap);
```

and load imgBitmap to your ImageView, I hope this will solve your problem.